# Making two extends in php with Yootheme's Zoo (Custom Element)

Tags: php, joomla2.5, element

I am trying to make a custom element using yootheme's CCK "ZOO" and I have run into a snag.  I think I need to extend two other elements to combine them to make a custom element.

It starts with

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// register ElementRepeatable class
App::getInstance('zoo')->loader->register('ElementRepeatable', 'elements:repeatable/repeatable.php');
// register ElementOption class
App::getInstance('zoo')->loader->register('ElementOption', 'elements:option/option.php');
```

I want to add this to call the class then extend and implement (I really don't know what this sentence means.)  I'm looking at two files and combining them.

```
class ElementCustomName  extends ElementOption extends ElementRepeatable implements iRepeatSubmittable {
```

then the actual code starts below that...

I'm just trying to figure out how to extend the ElementOption along with ElementRepeatable.

This is the error I get:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_EXTENDS, expecting '{'
```

It would be expecting on the class line.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**:

Attempt from First Comment

```
class ElementCustomName extends ElementOption {
/* Select Option - More Code Than This */
}

class ElementOption extends ElementRepeatable implements iRepeatable {
/* Text Option - More Code Than This */
}
```

**Fatal Error**:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ElementOption
```

Comment: I don't know much about joomla, but PHP doesn't support multiple inheritance like that. You have to declare them separately: `class ElementCustomName extends ElementOption {...} class ElementOption extends ElementRepeatable {...}`

Comment: hmm...that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: let me type out the code so that you can see how I put it...

Comment: I updated the post with what I thought you were saying.

Comment: You'll need someone who better understands how the Joomla classes work. The error makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple inheritance in PHP.
if you look at option.php and related.php you'll see they implement more or less the same methods.
if you want to do a chimera of those object copy and paste from the two classes and create your own element.
not elegant but it works.